# bash: scritp for kicking all ssh-entries execpt the localhost

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, networking, ssh

I'm writing a short script to put as a cronjob. The function of the script should be kicking all ssh-entries (all hosts that are connected via ssh on a  machine), except a special host (mostly localhost or the host where I'm sitting at). My idea was:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -f ssh)
```

But this kicks all ssh-entries (including the host where I'm sitting at). How can I change the script so that it won't kick the localhost ?

Comment: Are these other SSH sessions owned by you, or by other people?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is deny all ssh connections that are not coming from localhost. Go to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add a line that says `AllowUsers *@localhost`, then restart the ssh server. This will allow only users that come from localhost to connect via ssh. You can also use `DenyUsers youruser@yourdomain` if you want to blacklist specific users or domains. If users that you blacklisted/that are not on your whitelist try to connect, they'll get a Permission denied message.

Comment: I understand that he only wants to kick everybody out once a while but he wants to keep the ssh access to everybody. In some sort of "I kick everybody and if they are active they will reconnect". So maybe just restarting the ssh deamon?

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes Well restarting the ssh daemon would kick him too, he said he doesn't want the host he uses to be kicked. But I don't really see the point of just periodically kicking everyone?

Comment: that's true. I don't see the point neither but maybe he can describe the use case further so we can provide a more accurate solution.